# How to run function when wordpress theme is activated using define( 'WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'your-default-theme' );

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a theme for wordpress multisite. I'm using 
`define( 'WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'your-default-theme' );`
Now problem i'm facing is using `add_action("after_switch_theme", "create_initial_pages",10,2);` 
hook does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this in theme functions file:

```
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'create_initial_pages');

function create_initial_pages () {
    // your code
}
```

You should use wp_insert_post() function to insert new pages after switching the theme.

Comment: hey paul thanks for the reply, I'm using **after_switch_theme** hook, but my problem is it does not get called when I create new site (in multisite wordpress) beacuse in wp-config.php I have set my default theme using **define( 'WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'your-default-theme' );**